# How to handle Database Connection Error while running app using Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, database, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am having an issue that if Node server application is already running using Sequelize, then Database server has been crashed then it also close node process, how to handle it ?

I also checked on Sequelize repo issue https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1854

But error events not implemented yet.

Any idea, Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have global error handler in express (or what are you using)? Did you try to wrap all calls to DB with try/catch?

Comment: Or you wish to catch DB Connection Error only and react to it specifically?